# How to start DT datatable with all child rows expanded?

Tags: r, datatables, dt

In this [DT example](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/002-rowdetails.html) with child rows, how to start the table with all the child rows expanded?

```
library(DT)
datatable(
  cbind(' ' = '&oplus;', mtcars), escape = -2,
  options = list(
    columnDefs = list(
      list(visible = FALSE, targets = c(0, 2, 3)),
      list(orderable = FALSE, className = 'details-control', targets = 1)
    )
  ),
  callback = JS("
  table.column(1).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});
  var format = function(d) {
    return '<div style=\"background-color:#eee; padding: .5em;\"> Model: ' +
            d[0] + ', mpg: ' + d[2] + ', cyl: ' + d[3] + '</div>';
  };
  table.on('click', 'td.details-control', function() {
    var td = $(this), row = table.row(td.closest('tr'));
    if (row.child.isShown()) {
      row.child.hide();
      td.html('&oplus;');
    } else {
      row.child(format(row.data())).show();
      td.html('&CircleMinus;');
    }
  });"
))
```

[image]

PS: stackoverflow forced me to include more details to the question but there is nothing else to add...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your existing callback to also iterate over each row in the table. In that iteration you can create and open each child record:

```
table.rows().every( function () { 
  this.child( format(this.data()) ).show(); 
} );
```

This snippet needs to be appended to the end of your `callback = JS(...)` option as shown below:

```
  callback = JS(
    "
  table.column(1).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});
  var format = function(d) {
    return '<div style=\"background-color:#eee; padding: .5em;\"> Model: ' +
            d[0] + ', mpg: ' + d[2] + ', cyl: ' + d[3] + '</div>';
  };
  table.on('click', 'td.details-control', function() {
    var td = $(this), row = table.row(td.closest('tr'));
    if (row.child.isShown()) {
      row.child.hide();
      td.html('&oplus;');
    } else {
      row.child(format(row.data())).show();
      td.html('&CircleMinus;');
    }
  });
  table.rows().every( function () { 
    this.child( format(this.data()) ).show(); 
  } );"
  )
```

The result:

[image]